# vb to c# code conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am nearly complete on converting vb.net code to c#. Unfortunately, I am having problems in converting the following code to c#.

```
Public Event SomeSub(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Implements SomeLayer.ISomeInterface.SomeSub
```

Comment: Have a look at http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Telerik is based on https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :-

```
public event SomeSubEventHandler SomeLayer.ISomeInterface.SomeSub;
public delegate void SomeSubEventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e);
```

For future conversion you can use some converter tools as linked below :-

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=9fdbdc76-36a7-4d8a-a54a-e75b9ad8f5f8

http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: What's the reason for creating the `SomeSubEventHandler` delegate?

Comment: By defining a delegate, you are saying to the user of your class "Please feel free to put any method that match this signature here and it will be called each time my delegate is called". @sloth

Comment: Sorry, I rephrase my question: Why do you create a new delegate `SomeSubEventHandler` instead of using the [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate?

Comment: You can't declare events in C# via explicit interface style unless you provide the 'add' and 'remove' accessors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx

Comment: @RalphDeGuzman: Is that really what you need? It doesn't compile. Neel is right about needing the delegate - the original VB code used the implicit delegate style, available in VB, but not C#.

Answer (score 0):

It's just about [implementing an interface event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx).

There's really no need to define a whole new delegate since the event complies to the "standard" `EventHandler` signature (`Object` and `EventArgs` params).

```
public event EventHandler SomeSub;
```

You can then use it as:

```
instance.SomeSub += (s, e) => { //handle event here };
```